# Why does Snowflake give me a redacted error when running a procedure?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

Whenever I try to call a procedure with an SQL query in it, Snowflake displays <"redacted">

Is there a certain permission I'm missing?

Comment: Does the procedure look like it is running or erroring? Are you sure that "redacted" is not what the SP has been coded to return when it is run? Can you share the code for the SP?

Comment: If it's an error, the text will return in red. Possibly there's some kind of Masking policy in place or even a regular view that's checking `current_role()`. The default for running SPs is `execute as owner` if not specified, so the role may be different than the session calling the SP.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a new "feature", described here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2023-03-bcr#query-history-redacted-sql-upon-syntax-error

They explain they do it only for the queries with syntax error, for safety reason.

The user who run the query can see it, others see only the "redacted" string.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your query with the error msg in the query_history table

`select * from snowflake.account_usage.query_history where query_id = '<query id>'`

Comment: Nope, the query text with a syntax error is also "redacted" in this view.